# How to hide grey background color on click (react-native-popup-menu)

Tags: react-native-popup-menu

I'm using React native popup menu and on click I have a grey background color that appears on the menu.
So i read the docs and it says to change customStyles in Menu Trigger but I tried many different things and it doesn't work.
I just want that when I press the menu I have no background color.

[image]

Comment: Could you share some code reproducing your issue?

Comment: I recommend you to check https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/examples/TouchableExample.js - most likely you want to use `TouchableWithoutFeedback`

Comment: Thanks It worked using TriggerTouchableComponent